# Caption beside image in minipage

Tags: graphics, captions, minipage

What i'm trying to achieve:

Have two images in one page, one image on the top half of the page and the other the bottom half. Ive managed to do this by:

```
\vbox{
  \begin{minipage}[t][0.45\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{image1}
  \end{minipage}

  \nointerlineskip
  \begin{minipage}[b][0.45\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
    \vspace{0.4in}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=0.45\textheight]{image2}
  \end{minipage}
}
```

But i would like to have a caption beside the image so that it doesn't use up too much space. Ive tried a few ways but i always get the 'not in outer par mode' error.

Any way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to the site! have you tried `captionof` from the `caption` package?

Comment: You could use the  `floatrow` package, which is used to group figures or tables, and has an option `capposition=beside`.

Comment: So what else is on the page? Or do you just want to take up a full page with just two images - one at the top and one at the bottom? Also you make the images take up roughly half the text block width. Does that mean the caption should fill the rest on the opposing side?

Comment: Not sure on how to use <code>captionof</code> to place the caption on the side. <code>Floatrow</code> was one of the ones that caused the 'not in outer par mode' error. just two images at the moment. I really only want them referenced (e.g. Fig. 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option using `\captionof` from the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package (the `capt-of` package also offers this feature) to provide the captions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][0.45\textheight][t]{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\captionof{figure}{here's the caption for the first figure and some more text for the example}
\label{fig:testa}
\end{minipage}
\vfill

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][0.45\textheight][t]{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=0.45\textheight,width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{.45\textwidth}
\captionof{figure}{here's the caption for the second figure and some more text for the example}
\label{fig:testb}
\end{minipage}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the lengths and alignments used according to your needs.